# AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, tkinter, pil, pillow

```
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
def open_f():
       filename = fd.askopenfilename()
       img = Image.open("C:\Program\python курсы\otz.png")
def save_f():
       print('SAVE')
def save_as():
       print('SAVE AS')
window = Tk()
window.title('ImageBuy')
w = window.winfo_screenwidth()
h = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry('{}x{}'.format(w, h))
window.state('zoomed')
main_menu = Menu()
window.config(menu = main_menu)
file_menu = Menu(main_menu, tearoff = 0)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu = file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="Открыть", command = open_f)
file_menu.add_command(label="Сохранить", command = save_f)
file_menu.add_command(label="Открыть как", command = open_f)
file_menu.add_command(label="Сохранить как", command = save_as)
file_menu.add_command(label="Новый файл", command = open_f)
image_menu = Menu(main_menu, tearoff = 0)
main_menu.add_cascade(label = "Изображение", menu = image_menu)
image_menu.add_command(label="Информация")
w_canv = w//3 + w//2
h_canv = h//3 + h//2
fr = Frame()
line = Canvas(fr, width= w//40, height = h//3+h//2, bg= "white")
line.pack(side=LEFT)
line.create_line(w//160,0,w//160,h//3+h//2, width=2)
a= 0
for i in range((h//3+h//2)//1):
       if a<10:
              a+=1
              continue
       else:
              line.create_line(w//160, i, w//80, i)
              line.create_text(w//50, i, text = str(i), font = ("Arial", 5))
              a = 0
canv = Canvas(fr, width = w_canv, height = h_canv, bg="white")
canv.pack()
fr.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Это весь код и тут ошибка:

> AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
>   Из-за чего она?
>   Если всё что касается tkinter отключить, то PIL работает

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что в `tkinter` тоже есть `Image`, и когда вы импортируете всё содержимое из `tkinter`, этот `Image` замещает собой `Image` из `PIL`.

Вообще, импортировать через звёздочку - почти всегда плохая идея. Импортируйте либо прицельно те имена, которые будете использовать; либо импортируйте просто модуль (а не его содержимое), и в своём коде к его атрибутам обращайтесь через точку.